# How to build a filter handler for a custom file format so that its contents could be searched through the windows search?

Tags: c++, search, com, filter

I have started building a filter handler for a custom file format. I came to know that I need to implement the IFilter interface for that. Moreover, I got a sample from the internet which was doing just the needful. It registered the persistent handler for the custom file format in the regedit/classes_root. But still my custom files are not getting searched through their contents. Any suggestions..

Comment: You can use Process Monitor to see if your IFilter is loaded in the first place and what happens after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't done this, but [Developing Filter Handlers for Windows Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940430%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN seems like a good starting point.

Comment: +1, I have done that and that guide is the right place to start.

Comment: @sharptooth: Please give me some samples relating to this if possible.

Comment: @Jatin Sehgal: There's a sample IFilter in Windows SDK - you could start with making it work and then altering it to your needs. Feel free to ask specific questions as you go.

Comment: @sharptooth:Sir, I have already tried it. Actually its registering the custom file format with its persistent handler in the regedit but then also the system doesnt search the contents in the file with that file format.Example - .abc has been registered in the regedit and I create a file with jatin.abc now if I search for contents kept in the jatin.abc it will not be searched. Please suggest something. I have already wasted so many days on it.

Comment: @Jatin Sehgal: You use Process Monitor to see what goes wrong. You need to validate that 1. your IFilter is located, then 2. it is successfully loaded, then 3. its interfaces are used in some reasonable fashion - all methods return success or some reasonable error indication. That's a long road and you have to walk it step by step.

Comment: @sharptooth: I have downloaded the process monitor and added a filter for my filtersample path to it. But after that what to do? In short How should I use this Process Monitor in order to accomplish the 3 tasks mentioned by you?Thanks.

Comment: @Jatin Sehgal: If the indexing agent tries to load your IFilter you'll see an attempt to access the .dll file by the indexing agent process. If that doesn't happen you need to verify that it is located in the first place - look at registry accesses by the indexing agent process.